# NFC NDEF writing on IOS Encoding

Tags: ios, flutter, core-nfc

I am working on a flutter app which reads and writes to NFC-tags. On Android it works just fine. Now I am working on implementing NFC-writing on IOS since it is now available.

I do get the app to write a text-record to the tag. But somehow it is written in UTF16 which makes things break apart.

How do I create NFCNDEFPayload.wellKnownTypeTextPayload with a string that is UTF-8 encoded??

Comment: How do you get the app to write a text record to the tag? Like what is the code that is making it UTF16?

Comment: Hi, I managed to solve it using the NFCNDEFPayload.init constructor instead of NFCNDEFPayload.wellKnownTypeTextPayload.

Comment: Can you post your code as an answer? I'm having trouble doing it. When I make a payload with that it doesn't have the "en" in front of the data and if I write "enHello" then the text is en hello instead of hello.

Comment: Sure, this is how I do it now. I am not sure if the locale though. But I do not need that in my use case.

let textPayload2 = NFCNDEFPayload.init(
            format: NFCTypeNameFormat.nfcWellKnown,
            type: Data.init(count: 0),
            identifier: Data.init(count: 0),
            payload: tmpMessage.data(using: .utf8)!,
            chunkSize: 0)

Answer (score 7):

You got most of the way there. Here's a full working example which fixes a couple things (specifically missing 'type' specifier and locale usage):

```
var payloadData = Data([0x02,0x65,0x6E]) // 0x02 + 'en' = Locale Specifier
payloadData.append("Text To Write".data(using: .utf8)!)

let payload = NFCNDEFPayload.init(
    format: NFCTypeNameFormat.nfcWellKnown,
    type: "T".data(using: .utf8)!,
    identifier: Data.init(count: 0),
    payload: payloadData,
    chunkSize: 0)
```

Note that this sets the locale to 'en'.

I've tested tags created with this code on both iPhone and Android, and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Thanks. Thats great!

Comment: @Phil Powers for var payloadData = Data([0x02,0x65,0x6E]) what is the 0x02 supposed to represent? Like will that always be that? Is 0x65 and 0x6E the UTF NSData for "en"?

Comment: Yes - 0x02 is the prefix to indicate the language locale. 0x65 and 0x6E are the ASCII values for 'e' and 'n' - so I suppose you could specify a two-character language string and convert that to a Data if you needed to support locales other than English.