# CoreNFC Text message produces double byte chars only?

Tags: swift, core-nfc

I am successfully interfacing (reading & writing) to an NDEF tag. The tag is an NXP electronic tag on my proto board which I can read out with I2C protocol. I am working with plain text messages only.

Writing to the tag, though successful, generates double byte character text only. Creating a text message is done with:

```
guard let testRecord = NFCNDEFPayload.wellKnownTypeTextPayload(
  string: String(describing: "blah blah".cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)),
  locale: .current)
else { return }
```

and is written to the tag with:

```
let myMessage = NFCNDEFMessage.init(records: [testRecord])
tag.writeNDEF(myMessage)
```

The data arrives in the tag but is encoded (so it seems) as two bytes. Specifically, each character in the string "blah blah" is preceded with \x00, resulting into `\x00 \b \x00 \l \x00 \a` etc.

I thought that .utf8 encoding would drop to just standard ASCII (single byte) if one uses only characters within the ASCII set.

How can I make sure the NDEF message is encoded with single character ASCII?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone landing here, the short answer is; yes, NFCNDEFPayload.wellKnownTypeTextPayload() encodes strings as utf16 only (nice job documenting this Apple!). To solve this, you need to go a layer down by constructing your own payload. Check out this answer: [NFC NDEF writing on IOS Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58115985/nfc-ndef-writing-on-ios-encoding)